# How to retrieve pK using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I implement this method of the **UserDetailService** interface,

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        final EmailCredential userDetails = persistentEmailCredential
                .getUniqueEmailCredential(username);
        if (userDetails == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + "is not registered");
        }
        final HashSet<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));

    for (UserRole role:userDetails.getAccount().getRoles()) {
        authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.getRole()));
    }

    return new User(userDetails.getEmailAddress(), userDetails
            .getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
            authorities);
}
```

In the security context I do some thing like this:

```
    <!-- Login Info -->
    <form-login default-target-url='/dashboard.htm' login-page="/login.htm"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?authfailed=true"
        always-use-default-target='false' />

    <logout logout-success-url="/login.htm" invalidate-session="true" />
    <remember-me user-service-ref="emailAccountService" key="fuellingsport" />
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>

</http>
```

Now I want to pop out the Pk of the logged in user.

How can I show it in my jsp pages?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this, which can be used in jsp.

```
<security:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own class extending `User` with required fields and return it from `UserDetailsService`.

Then you can access these fields as pointed out by Raghuram:

```
<security:authentication property="principal.pk"/>
```